# Merge fonts to generate multi locale PDF in Java

Tags: java, html, css, pdf, fonts

I am trying to generate PDF using iText for all locale. It's like PDF can have characters from any languages supported by noto sans and noto sans cjk. I do not know in advance which character may be used in PDF. Itext doesnot give any fallback as well. I decided to merge these two fonts in one. Is it possible?

Here is code snippet I am using to do all this:

```
  public static void generatePDF(String inputFileName, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(fileName);
            os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
            renderer.setDocument(new File(inputFileName));
            renderer.layout();
            renderer.createPDF(os);
        } catch(Exception e){

        }finally {
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
@font-face {
font-family: Noto Serif;
src: url("GoogleNotoSerif-Regular-V1-1.ttf");
-fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;
-fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;
}

* {
    font-family: Noto Serif;
 }
```

In above code, I want to use font-family name as some common name and that file will be merged as a result of both fonts i.e. Noto Sans and Noto Sans CJK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't merge noto and noto-cjk into a single font. The whole reason they're separate is that the full set of characters supported by both fonts is more than fits in a single font file (which have a hard limit of 65355 distinct shapes, which includes shapes used as compositional parts of other shapes).

(more details about that in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31169546/740553))

Also, a PDF is not like a plain text file: PDF files are a markup format, where stretches of text *explicitly* say which font resource they are tied to. They are not "plain text and then the PDF reader picks whatever font would work for that", PDF are strictly typeset data.